# Z-boson left and right handed cross-section

Tags: particle-physics

In the following paper [Here](http://inspirehep.net/record/356288/files/slac-pub-6169.pdf), the left-right asymmetry is given by $A_{LR}:=\frac{\sigma_L-\sigma_R}{\sigma_L+\sigma_R}$, and it directly gives $A_{LR}=\frac{2c_V\cdot c_A}{c_V^2+c_A^2}$. Can someone show me a paper that gives the computation. Appreciated!